# Simplify Boolean Expression example

Tags: java

how to simplify

```
if ( this.something == false )
```

this boolean expression ?
 Actually I want to ask is what is *Simplify Boolean Expression*?

Comment: `if (!this.something)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
if (!this.something)
```

You can use boolean variables directly:

**Example:**

```
boolean flag = true;
if(flag) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like following since if expression need a boolean value.

```
if (!this.something) {
//
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator for more simplification :

```
int someVariable = (this.something) ? 0:1;
```

`someVariable` will be 1 if `this.something` is `false`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify boolean expression is to reduce complexity of this expression, with preserving the meaning.

In your case:

```
if(!this.something)
```

has the same meaning but it's a little bit shorter.

To simplify more complex examples you can use truth tables or Karnaugh maps.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the if statement wants to evaluate whatever is within it into a boolean
if

```
boolean something = true;
if(something == true) evaluates to true
if(something != true) evaluates to false
```

but you can also do

```
if(something) evaluates to whatever something is (true in this case)
if(!something) evaluates to opposite what something is (false in this example)
```

Also you can simplify if statements in certain cases by using a ternary operator:

```
boolean isSomethingTrue = (something == true) ? true : false;
boolean isSomethingTrue = something ? true : false;
type variable = (condition) ? return this value if condition met : return this value if condition is not met;
```